# Google apps script not throwing exception

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been playing around google apps script for a while, and I stumbled across the "Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell" error. But when I tried to prevent my script from crashing because of it, using try-catch statement, it didn't work.

I checked in the Google apps script documentation site (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), and found nothing.

Moreover, I tried to run that sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  try
  {
    var a = ""
    for (i =  0; i< 50000; i++)
       a += '111'
       SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById("FileID")).getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue(a)
  }
  catch (e)
  {
     Logger.log(e.message)
  }
}
```

And it crashed, leaving no record in the log.

Any idea on how to prevent crashing? preferably with some code segment that will allow me to manipulate the input?

I will be grateful for any help.

### EDIT

My script should handle big amounts of data, so running time is really important for me. Right now I'm using a solution that looks like

```
a.substring (0,50000)
```

But the thing that I really want to see is something that will be activated only when needed, so it will be faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue of catching the "Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell" error use SpreadsheetApp.flush();

```
function myFunction() {
  try
  {
    var a = ""
    for (i =  0; i< 50000; i++)
       a += '111'
       SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById("FileID")).getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue(a);
       SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  catch (e)
  {
     Logger.log(e.message)
  }
}
```

Note: I am not answering the performance issue as I think that has been addressed in the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
var CELL_MAX_LEN = 50000; // Or whatever value you choose

function checkAndWriteCellValue(range, value) {
  if (value.length > CELL_MAX_LEN) {
    value = 'Too long!'; // Or something else, truncate value etc
  }
  range.setValue(value);
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
var range = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(...); // Add the specifics of your range
checkAndWriteCellValue(range, value);
```

Comment: This will work very nicely, but since my script should handle a large amounts of data, running time is really a big issue. The solution is good, just not fit for my case...

Comment: Then I'd suggest you use `setValues` anyway, and pass a 2d array. You could easily check the entire array for those where values are longer than 50000. It will perform much better than `setValue`. I would suggest that repeated use of `setValue` as opposed to using `setValues` will be much more of a slow down than checking string lengths.

Comment: I am aware of the slow time of read/write operation on google sheet. This is not my problem. I want to know if there is any handle/exception that the script will throw if such error will accrue...